# jwplayer ---> how to get the file name of a stream to play it with jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

Anyone here has experience with the universal jwplayer?
The reason I'm asking is coz I've installed everything correctly and i'm not sure how to get the file from a stream to play it with the jwplayer...

In other words, i need the file name and i have no idea how to get it..

this is the location of the stream I'm trying to play using jwplayer:
http://www.canalsuralacarta.es/directo/ver/andalucia-television

what would be the file name? so i can play it with jwplayer

i.e code

```
<div id="tv">Loading the player ...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("tv").setup({
        flashplayer: "../jwplayer_5.5/player.swf",
        file: ?????????????????   help!,
        height: 270,
        width: 480
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the file you need to load into your player:
http://andaluciatelevision.rtva.stream.flumotion.com/rtva/andaluciatelevisionh264.flv.m3u

To find this link... Use Internet Explorer, go to the Andalucia TV website.  Then while you are watching the TV stream, use the developer tools.  Select the Script tab.  Scroll through the information.  You will find the above link as a src (source) under the script portion of the tools.

This video is H.264 and I am not sure if JW player can play this type of compressed format.

I use VLC player because it plays almost anything you give it.  I am watching Andalucia TV right now using VLC player.  I suggest you download and install VLC instead of JW player.  It is free and you can get it here: 
http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html

I hope you enjoy this channel.

Comment: Internet Explorer?? Seriously?